# 毎日日本語を話せし、たくさん所きれいだし、日本で本当に住むがほしいです

Tags: sentence

I'm constructing a sentence where I want to say that "I really want to live in Japan because then I would be able to speak Japanese every day, and because it has many beautiful places" the way I've written it is below:

> 毎日日本語を話せし、たくさん所きれいだし、日本で本当に住むがほしいです。

I honestly feel a bit weird writing this myself because something seems off about the sentence altogether. Am I allowed to put a potential form before し in this manner? is there anything here that I could improve in terms of sentence structure.

Comment: For the potential form, did you mean 話せるし・・・?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense, but there are a bunch of errors in it.

Comment: @mamster, kettleman *must* have meant   話せるし

Answer (score 1):

> 毎日日本語を話せし、たくさん所きれいだし、日本で本当に住むがほしいです。

There are small errors in each part of what you want to say, unfortunately. Or fortunately, if you consider this a chance to study the language. It was already pointed out in the comments that you were trying to use the potential form, but mis-wrote it,  it should be 毎日日本語を話せるし、... In your next sentence fragment, you apparently leave out several connecting particles, and/or need to rearrange your word order. In English we would say "there are many beautiful places" but in Japanese the most common word order would become "beautiful places many (are there)." Rather than telling you outright, I hope you challenge yourself to rearranging the words on your own. One thing I will say is don't forget that before a noun, きれい is a な adjective... and "are there" is represented by an existence verb, the one for inanimate objects.  ... However, if you actually wanted to say it as "Many places there are beautiful." THEN, your word order is correct, you just left out a couple simple one syllable connective particles. There should be one between "many" and "places", and a different one between "places" and "beautiful"... Make a choice about which way you mean to say that middle section, and you should be able to fix it up on your own without much difficulty.  At the end, 日本で本当に住むがほしいです。... 日本で is not "wrong" precisely, but で is used to name a place where some action is occurring, and with 住む, which is more a "state of being" or connected to "going" somewhere (to live) the particle most commonly used is に. As for the way you wrote 住む, you should either change it to the "したい" form, or use の to change it to its noun version, because you can only "ほしい" nouns.

Comment: Since the author of this answer didn’t give the correct example after explaining all the errors, I’m gonna give a “fixed” version based on this answer: 「毎日日本語を話せるし、たくさんの綺麗な所があるし、日本に住むのが本当にほしいです。」